# Adding a custom check-box to the customizer panel in wordpress to enable/disable some html content

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to be able to enable or disable the display of HTML content, like the header enables/disables checkbox.

I've seen some functions like add_controls, add_settings, etc, but all I've found are controls that change color or adds the background image.

Thanks for the answers and sorry for my mistakes, it's my first post.

EDITED: SOLVED 
I've created the custom setting and controls(checkbox) with the add_section(), add_setting() and add_control() functions. Then used the get_theme_mod() function to check the value of the checkbox and with a conditional "if" execute the html code created in the article.php page of my chIild theme

Answer (score 0):

> The disabled attribute is a boolean attribute.
>
> When present, it specifies that the element should be disabled.
>
> A disabled element is unusable.
>
> The disabled attribute can be set to keep a user from using the
>   element until some other condition has been met (like selecting a
>   checkbox, etc.). Then, a JavaScript could remove the disabled value,
>   and make the element usable.

Button Example
A disabled button:

```
<button type="button" disabled>Click Me!</button>
```

Fieldset Example
Disable a group of related form elements:

```
<fieldset disabled>
  <legend>Personalia:</legend>
  Name: <input type="text"><br>
  Email: <input type="text"><br>
  Date of birth: <input type="text">
</fieldset>
```

Input Example
An HTML form with a disabled input field:

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" disabled><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Optgroup Example
A disabled option-group:

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="German Cars" disabled>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Option Example
A drop-down list with one disabled option:

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo" disabled>Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Select Example
A disabled drop-down list:

```
<select disabled>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Textarea Example
A disabled text area:

```
<textarea disabled>
At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. We offer free tutorials in all web development technologies. 
</textarea>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_disabled.asp